# Laravel - get the top 5 by number of occurrences

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I have tables comments, votes, views, likes which have article_id field. I am trying to get first 5 articles from those tables, by the number of occurrences in them. I am sending `$modelName` to my function and then trying to get results from the queries. This is how my query looks like now:

```
private function query($modelName) {
        $mostSomethingArticle = $modelName->all()->groupBy('article_id')->take(5);

        return $mostSomethingArticle;

      }
```

Right now, I am getting, this kind of result:

```
Collection {#398 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    5 => Collection {#377 ▼
      #items: array:5 [▶]
    }
    2 => Collection {#376 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }
    6 => Collection {#397 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▶]
    }
    1 => Collection {#396 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }
    7 => Collection {#395 ▼
      #items: array:5 [▶]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am wondering how to make a query where I would get first 5 results with the number of occurrences in `'desc'` order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am posting my workaround if anyone will need it in the future, instead of passing a `$modelName`, I have decided to get the name of the table from $request and then do the query like this:

```
$result = DB::table($request['option'])
                ->select(DB::raw('article_id'), DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
                ->groupBy('article_id')
                ->orderBy('count', 'desc')
                ->take(5)
                ->get();
```

Comment: Nice workaround, but it'll be better if you could do this using directy eloquent request.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that what you mean but if you have a column that contain `occurrences` you could order first by this column then get the result :

```
$modelName->all()->groupBy('article_id')->sortByDesc('occurrences')->take(5);
```

Try also :

```
$mostSomethingArticle = $modelName->all()->groupBy('article_id')->sortByDesc(function($model)
{
    return $model->occurrences;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this already but I get an error since you can't use orderBy on collection.

Comment: I have tried it, but I still get the same result. I have come up with a different solution.